# Configuring and running integrated weblogic server in jdeveloper

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

i know this can be very simple but i am not able to do so.
I am trying to start integrated weblogic server in jdeveloper(v11.1.1.7.0). But it always says the following error :

```
*** Using port 7101 ***
C:\Users\595452\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.7.40.64.93\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
The system cannot find the path specified.
The JRE was not found in directory C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\jdk160_29. (JAVA_HOME)
Please edit your environment and set the JAVA_HOME
variable to point to the root directory of your Java installation.
Press any key to continue . . . [Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer is shutting down.  All applications currently running will be terminated and undeployed.]
```

My Java_home is set to the jdk i have installed and also have an entry in PATH of system variable.

```
**User variable:**

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

**System Variable :**
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

Please assist me in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the install routine thinks that your JAVA_HOME is set to the wrong jre. First test is to open a command shell and type in "java -version" 
Verify that you see Java 1.7.0 and not 1.6.0 
One this had been checked check the ide.conf file or jdev.conf file which java version is configured there.  There you should see jdk 1.7.0 configured. 
Then you remove the DefaultDomain folder out of the system 11.1.1.x.x.x folder. 
Then start jdev again and try to start the integrated server again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timo. I just had a new domain..that worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

I fixed mine by editing the `setDomainEnv.cmd` in my weblogic installation. 
In my installation `D:\srv\wls12120\user_projects\domains\mydomain\bin` my installation pointed to:

```
set SUN_JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk\jdk8u40 changed to 
set DEFAULT_SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_2


set DEFAULT_SUN_JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk\jdk8u40 changed to 
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_2
```

as well as here:

```
if "%VM_TYPE%"=="JRockit" (
    set JAVA_HOME=%BEA_JAVA_HOME%
) else (
    if "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="Sun" (
        set JAVA_HOME=%SUN_JAVA_HOME%
    ) else (
        set JAVA_VENDOR=Oracle
        set JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk\jdk8u40
        set VM_TYPE=HotSpot
    )
)
```

This has solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Windows 7

Delete the C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.2.36.55.36 folder and then restart your JDeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.2.36.55.36` folder and then restart your JDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading Java version, remove all the files available in the below path

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper